# How can I handle alert using if else condition in selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

`else` is perfectly executed but `if` block is not executed - can anyone help me?

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Maf_Base.getDriver(), 10 /*timeout in seconds*/);

if(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())==null) {  
    System.out.println("alert was not present");
    agobj.logout.click();
} else {
    Alert alert = Maf_Base.getDriver().switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
    System.out.println("alert was present and accepted");
}
```

Comment: Two thoughts - is an alert actually present? - Is waiting until alertISPresent to be *null* just timing out after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 4):

Try a [try catch](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp), if something in the try gives a timeout exception (e.g. alert not found) it will execute the code in the catch block.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Maf_Base.getDriver(), 10);

try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
    Alert alert = Maf_Base.getDriver().switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
    System.out.println("alert was present and accepted");
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("alert was not present");
    System.out.print(e);
    agobj.logout.click();
}
```

Comment: *"Thus it reads: if(functionObject == null) {} and a functionObject is not null it is a Object."* it is not actually true (if I got you right). `ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()` is "function object" but not `wait.until(functionObject)`. So it does not read `if(functionObject == null) {}` but rather `if(alert==null)` where `alert` is a product of `functionObject.apply()` that is called inside `until` method. However `alert` cannot be `null` since `until` just throw an exception if it would be null. However I agree with general idea of looking up the alert.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I am not a Java expert, but the wait.until returns an alert, but while it is waiting it is not an alert. An IF comparison in most languages do not wait for the return of a function, it just compares the objects in its current state. Still the try/catch will probably solve the issue.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Removed my assumption of how Java works :)

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal thanks, bro!! it's working properly

Answer (score 3):

If you check `wait.until()` code:

[image]

You will know that it never returns null. It either returns found `alert` (see lines 88-92) or throws an exception. This is why your if does not work.